# Increment a field conditioned by a WHERE

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Sequelize. I have an instance from `findOne`, and I want to increment one of its fields using an expression, and only under certain conditions. Something such as:

`UPDATE Account SET balance = balance - 10 WHERE balance >= 10;`

I want the db to calculate the expression, as this isn't happening in a transaction. So I can't do a `SET balance = 32`. (I *could* do `SET balance = 32 WHERE balance = 42`, but that's not as effective.) I don't want to put a `CHECK` in there, as there are other places where I do want to allow a negative balance.

(Our Sequelize colleague has left, and I can't figure out how to do this).

1. I see the `instance.increment` and `decrement`, but it doesn't look like they take a `where` object.
2. I don't see how to express the setting of `balance = balance - 10`, nor of expressing the expression in the `where` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for Model.decrement instead of instance.decrement.  instance.decrement is for updating the specific record so `where` doesn't make sense.

Model.decrement: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-decrement](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-decrement)

The example in the link shows similar scenario as yours.

============================================

Update:

This translates to your example.

```js
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

Account.decrement('balance', {
  by: 10,
  where: {
    balance: {
      [Op.gte]: 10
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Emma. What's the technique I need to use to have the decrement value equal an expression involving a field? And is that expression (and the `where` expression) evaluated by the db server? (On a smaller note, I think a 'where' on an instance would make sense if I want it to update only if the condition is true, yes?)

Comment: `where` is evaluated in server, so if the current value in DB at the time of execution is >= 10, the value is decremented by 10.  If the value is lower than 10, the value will stays as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Emma comments, here's what I have working. `amountToAdd` is just that; `cash_balance` is the field I'm incrementing. The check on `cash_balance` ensures that if I'm decrementing (that is `amount_to_add` is < 0), the balance doesn't go below 0. I need to muck around with that some.

```
const options = {
  where: {
    user_id: userId,
    cash_balance: {
      [ Op.gte ]: amountToAdd,
    },
  },
  by: amountToAdd
};
const incrResults = await models.User.increment( 'cash_balance', options );
```